# How do I build a sloped roof with a 60° rake?

Tags: building, angles

I've seen the sloped roof on the "[Winter Village Post Office](https://brickset.com/sets/10222-1/Winter-Village-Post-Office)" and similar using plates, and I want to build a roof with a similar angle:

[image: Steeply Raked Roofs]

What should I use to ensure they are well attached?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

See the [instruction for that set](http://cache.lego.com/bigdownloads/buildinginstructions/4658274.pdf) on pages 56-59, 65 and 68/69 for the 3 different roofs of it.

they're using a different technique and different pieces for all of them, so this perfectly shows up some alternatives (technic-like parts for the big roof to the right, blocks with studs on the sides for the small 90°-roofs and [1x1 with clips](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=2555) for the roof to the left).

[image: Technic Tile 1x2 with 2 holes, 1x2 Brick with Axle Hole] [image: Tile 1x1 with Clip, Plate 1x2 with Handle on End]

Answer (score 16):

In the past, LEGO produced a perfect element for this:

[image: Slope Brick 53 3 x 1 x 3 & 1/3 with Studs]

It's probably hard to find in big quantities now, so I give it more for reference than anything. I wish LEGO would still produce it though (not to mention its educative value).

Comment: That's an interesting piece I've never seen (nor have in my collection).  I wonder what made Lego abandon it?

Comment: I imagine they stopped producing it because you can create the same slope with other available elements (like hinges), and those other elements provide a much wider range of building possibilities.

Comment: Maybe they didn't like the fact that the angles are not integer (53,13° at the bottom); but then again they have Technic beams with the same angles. I'm quite curious too as to why they stopped it..

Answer (score 15):

To keep it simple I would use hinges placed on top of the wall, connect the roof plates and angle them to fit.

[image] <-- or -->   [image]

**Edit**: You could even add a small plate hinge at the roof ridge, under the roof plates.  This would keep them from separating.

[image][image]