# Building technique for plate at near 45 degree angle

Tags: building

Trying to construct an octagon shaped hallway and trying to attach plates at a near 45 degree angle, but have no idea how to do this. Are there any techniques for attaching plates at a near 45 degree angle that are gapless. Maybe using the technic bent lift arm pieces?

See photo below. Can't get the red brick to line up satisfactory.

[image]

Comment: Do you need the studs of the plates on the outside or can they also face the inside of the hallway?

Comment: Studs of the plates need to be on the outside

Comment: You might find that the answers to [How do I build a sloped roof with a 60° rake?](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/440/56) help as well - they won't join up completely, but you can probably hide the gaps sufficiently.

Answer (score 3):

**ROUND 2.**

***[HERE](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1neCAKCmIohQeXlyd2jX5ZuQ5TnOnjGuW)***, experiment with this new *greeblin*' compatible *.LXF* file.

***EDIT:***  Added X-ray animation to better see the internal contruction.

[image]

[image]

Please excuse the non-symmetrical sloppiness of this draft (I got lazy).

Note: The non-connecting hinges, and 1x1 circular pieces are to help cover the visible plate gaps.

We all know *LEGO Digital Draw* gets anal with the exact distances between pieces, so even if these hinges don't connect on this digital plane doesn't mean they won't in a real life physical build.

Oh, and the structural integrity is not based on the connectivity of said hinges.

I stole the idea from *[Set #7661 Jedi Starfighter with Hyperdrive Booster Ring](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=7661-1&name=Jedi%20Starfighter%20with%20Hyperdrive%20Booster%20Ring&category=%5BStar%20Wars%5D%5BStar%20Wars%20Episode%203%5D#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D)*, and added a bit o' me own *greeblin*';)

[image]

Comment: Sadly this approach won’t help either. Started off using something similar with sloped bricks, but need to attach greebling to the top of the outside face of the “hallway”

Comment: But the outside has studs all around, except for the underside.

Comment: Hey  Aziraphale!  'Sup. I was going by Random21's original image.  His bottom 1x4 plate isn't upside down.  It's positioned right-side up to connect the two opposing hinges. I know you'd asked him a question on the direction he wants the studs to face. I took it that he really wanted the 45 degree plates studs accessible, I'm not totally sure he wanted the sides studed up either, even though, I went ahead and did it.  He said he needed to attach greebling to the top of the outside face of the hallway.  I think I went overboard by attaching studs to all side except the bottom.